# Javascript scope in switch statement

Tags: javascript, scope, switch-statement

I'm new to Javascript and don't understand the following behaviors.

1. When the textarea is empty, the "process" code doesn't recognize it as null, and doesn't prompt for text.
2. When there is text in the textarea, the "process" code does not display the text in the alert. It seems this may be a scope problem I think all my variables are global.

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="button" name="btnProcessTA" onclick="myTextArea('process')" value="Process Text Area" />
<input type="button" name="btnClearTA"   onclick="myTextArea('clear')" value="Clear Text Area" />

<form id="formExample" action="" method="get">   
    <label for="textAreaField">A text area field</label>
    <textarea name="textAreaField" id="textAreaField" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myTextArea(op)
{
 oTextArea = document.getElementById("textAreaField"); 
 textAreaValue = oTextArea.value;           
 alert(op + "\n" + oTextArea + "\n" + textAreaValue);

 switch (op){
    case "clear":
    oTextArea.value = "";
    alert("Clearing");
    break;

    case "process":
    if (textAreaValue = "")
        alert("Would you please enter some text?"); 
    else
        alert("You entered:\n\n" + textAreaValue);
    break;

    default : alert("unknown op code");
    }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (textAreaValue = "")
```

to

```
if (textAreaValue === "") // or ==
```

You are performing assignment instead of doing a comparison.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed both problems.

Answer (score 2):

To compare, you have to use `==` instead of `=`  :)

```
case "process":
if (textAreaValue == "")
    alert("Would you please enter some text?"); 
else
    alert("You entered:\n\n" + textAreaValue);
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (textAreaValue = "")
```

The single equal sign in the if statement is interpreted as an assignment (It doesn't throw an error because technically it's correct syntax, but many people make this mistake by using a single equal sign instead of the double equal sign). The correct syntax would be the triple equal sign if you are intending to compare instead of assign.

```
if (textAreaValue === "")
```